# Local Moran's I on spatially heterogeneously sampled dataset

Tags: moran-index, geoda

I have a dataset where points are sampled in space. Values are attached to the points, and I'd like to check if these values are correlated in space with Geoda's local Moran's I.

However, the sampled data leads to a naturally very clustered spatial distribution of points. As such:

[image]

Does this forbid an analysis such as local Moran's I? If so, maybe choosing a large enough distance threshold to compute the weighting matrix could make it work?

Comment: You can use a LISA statistic on this data, just pay heed to the p and z values as you will see many non-significant values in this data. Also, please read up on the LISA statistic and what it is telling you. It is not just a spatial correlation statistic. It is indicating spatial outliers, commonly referred to as nonstationarity. You can also interpret the juxtaposition of local values eg., low-low, low-high, high-high, high-low. Thinking of the statistic along the lines of a Pearson's coefficient is an incorrect interpretation. You can however, integrate back to the global statistic.